# Arq app — Merge a backup folder from a fresh install

Tags: macos, backup, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

## context

I'm using [Arq app](http://www.haystacksoftware.com/arq/index.php), my disk have 2 partitions, `os` and `data`, the partition I'm backing up is `data`.

1. added the content under `data` partition to backup and waited for the data upload to complete
2. at some point I install a fresh copy OSX and want to continue backing up the `data` partition
3. reconfigure Arq to use same bucket as before
4. repeat steep 1

## question

At this point the backup data was duplicated with a different hash inside the same bucket. How can I update/merge the same backup?

I didn't try to restore, but that would be a hard price to pay since I've 300GB of data that is already available locally and since I use Glacier as storage method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click the triangle next to "Other Computers". (Or if you're using Arq 3, hover your mouse over "Other Backup Sets" and click the "Show" link).
There you'll find your old backup data. Select it and click the "Adopt This Backup Set".
This will cause Arq to adopt the settings and backup data it was using on your old computer, so you don't have to re-upload.

(I'm the creator of Arq)

Comment: This is great!!! Sorry superuser about the +1 comment, but I couldn't avoid it =P